# no option to play disc on xbox one

Tags: xbox-one

I bought a used Xbox One, reset it and made a new account. I put a brand new game in "Ark Survival" but there was no option anywhere on the Xbox to play it. With or with out the game in the Xbox there is no option to play a disc or to insert a disc. Everything works very well, and as it should but I can not find this option. Will this force me to download the game from the app store and pay for it again?(didn't buy the first game from store, it is on a disc) No activation code came with the game so that is not an option to download that way.

Comment: All disc games have to be installed onto the hard drive of the Xbox One.  After installing it, you need the disc in the Xbox to start the game.  It's been a long time since I've used a disc, but there has to be an option to install it somewhere.  I wouldn't try it via the store, since that sounds like you would have to purchase it.

Comment: Thank you, i understand you have to download it, but there is no option for me to do that process.

Comment: You don't have to download it, if you insert the disc into the system and it doesn't automatically start installing/create a tile for you in the "my games and apps" section of the console, that sounds like an issue with the disk drive itself.

Comment: Silly question, are you hooked up to the internet?  I had a similar issue with Mass Effect 2 where I thought I could play it offline without the disc, but do to weird circumstances (I originally used a disc, then bought the whole game at the Store so I could play without the disc, which I had lost), I had to delete the whole game from the hard drive then re-install (download) the game.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might come from disabling "Automatic updates" during console setup. Despite the Xbox running a lengthy update during installation, there were still two Microsoft Store updates that I found while troubleshooting this problem. **Install both updates and game discs should automatically detect after insertion.**

This problem doesn't seems unintuitive because there's an option for "Automatically play disc when inserted".